# Using a PIL Image with flasks send_file without saving to disk?

Tags: flask, python-imaging-library, bytesio

I'm saving the PIL image to a io.BytesIO() object.

```
imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
img.save(imgByteArr, format=format)
```

Then trying to return the image to the user.

```
return send_file(img.getvalue(), mimetype="image/" + img_details["ext"].lower())
```

But I'm getting the error

```
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

I dont want to send as an attachment, i want the image to be displayed on the page.

Does any one know if it is possible without saving to disk first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing "seek"

```
imgByteArr = io.BytesIO()
img.save(imgByteArr, format=format)
imgByteArr.seek(0)

return send_file(imgByteArr, mimetype="image/" + img_details["ext"].lower())
```

This now works.